# Add a label to a mouse pointer

Tags: openlayers-2, labeling, bearing, mouse-position, mouse-cursor

I am drawing a bearing line using a line with max vertices of 2, I have the calculations for figuring out the actual bearing from the lat lon of the original point and the mouse latlon

I want to place the label on the actual mouse before the second point is placed and the line feature is drawn.

Is this actually possible?

```
getMouseBearing : function(firstLatLon)
{
    this.map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition());

    this.map.events.register("mousemove", map, function(e) {
        var mousePosition = this.getLonLatFromPixel(e.xy);
        var bearing = getLineData(false, mousePosition, firstLatLon);
        //Need something here to add label to mouse cursor
    });
},
```

Comment: Unable to give you details this quickly, but for now, you could look into converting the map coordinates into screen coordinates and then using those to place a div on the fly.

Comment: I won't need to convert, already got them. I have thought of this, but was thinking doing that would b heavier than just adding a label

Comment: I know this has been asked before, and I have seen it implemented. Maybe even on the official OL page. Could not find it quickly now, but I hope someone else can point you in the right direction. Either way I tink they used a div, but I could be totally wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what about

```
<div id="tooltip"></div>
```

--

```
 map.events.register("mousemove", map, function (e) {
    var position = map.getLonLatFromViewPortPx(e.xy);

    OpenLayers.Util.getElement("tooltip").innerHTML = "<label>Latitude: " + position.lat + "</label><br/><label>Longitude: " + position.lon + "</label>";
    $("#tooltip").css({position:"absolute", left:e.x+15,top:e.y});
});
```

see jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/56gd9eb1/

Comment: Ah, see, i wasn't sure JQ worked inside a OL function like that (i'm still at noob at this)